# Tooltip not working on mobile/ipad but works on laptop

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify's tooltip component but it doesn't work on mobile devices but works on the laptop. How can I make it work on mobile/iPad devices?

```
<v-text-field required
  label='Information'
  v-model='dummy.name'
  :rules='nameRule'>
</v-text-field>

<v-tooltip left>
 <v-icon class="icon-align" small slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon>
 <span>Please enter information.</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: By "not working", do you mean it's not displaying?

Comment: @tony19 yes that's right. It doesn't work.

Comment: How are you trying to make it display?

Comment: @tony19 sorry I didnt understand your question.

Comment: What action are you performing to make the tooltip appear?

Comment: @tony19 Like tooltip has a feature to display the span message on hover. So since we can not hover on mobile devices I think we need to make it as a button so as the message appears on click in mobile devices.

Comment: The tooltip appears on mobile by pressing and holding on the target (e.g., a button).

Comment: @tony19 yes you are right. But it doesn't appear by pressing and holding.

Comment: Can you provide a demo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @tony19 I checked it properly by deploying it to the testing server and it is working. Press and hold works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and enabling the `open-on-click` attribute solved it:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-open-on-click

Answer (score 0):

For me, with vuetify version 2.3.4 the tooltip is activated on touch in tablet and mobile devices. In some cases, it was not usable and I had to control it by disabling property checking the breakpoint. You can try to define a [custom activator](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props). Here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53805098/9485417)